# MySQL LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table structure as follows:

registered (1 to 0/1) cobuy (1 to 0/*) cobuy_area_instance (0/* to 1) area

A search on a registered user list must return users from left to right, e.g it must return registered users with no cobuy profile, those with a cobuy rofile but no area, and those with all three.

I know this should be achieved by a left join, but am unclear as to how best to approach. I need fields from the registered table, cobuy table and area table, depending on what exists.

Any help appreicated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT R.FIELD_1, C.FIELD_2, CAI.FIELD_3
FROM REGISTERED R
LEFT OUTER JOIN COBUY C ON R.UID=C.UID
LEFT OUTER JOIN COBUY_AREA_INSTANCE CAI ON C.CID=CAI.CID
```

Should give you every item from the REGISTERED table plus any existing items from the COBUY table and any existing items from the COBUY_AREA_INSTANCE table.

Note that I deal with MSSQL so the syntax may not be correct.

Edited for WHERE clause on joins.

```
SELECT R.FIELD_1, C.FIELD_2, CAI.FIELD_3
FROM REGISTERED R
LEFT OUTER JOIN COBUY C ON (R.UID=C.UID AND C.DATE > '2011-02-14')
LEFT OUTER JOIN COBUY_AREA_INSTANCE CAI ON C.CID=CAI.CID
```

Seems like the solution to me.

Comment: I have a curious question for you, if I may; how would I include in the query, a specific where clause on a field in cai (from the example) and yet always include the registered users that do not have a rown in c or cai? I have tried including the where on the join and then as a where at the end, but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: Much kudos. Will have a bash and see how I get on :)

Comment: Ah, hmmm. I am wanting a 'where cai.user=c.user' on cai and c in particular. I have not tried, but it looks like extending your solution would result in a null set if cai had no rows for the user? I need it to return the registered user even if they do not fulfill the where on cai (due to their row not existing) - does that make sense?

Comment: if you do C.USER = CAI.USER in the left join it will return every record from C but only those from CAI that match the criteria.